# Finding hurricane metadata

Tags: metadata, united-states, weather

How do I find metadata shapefiles for hurricanes that occurred in Florida? I have tried searching for it but I don't know what I'm looking at.

Comment: You don't want metadata. You want **data** which has metadata. Randomly procured metadata is of no use whatsoever, which is why you can't find it.

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to look is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: maybe here https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/

Answer (score 3):

Hurricane **IDALIA**

Data from
https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/archive_forecast_results.php?id=al10&year=2023&name=Hurricane%20IDALIA

Unzipped Shapefiles have quite a lot of attribute information.

For Example: Day 14 Tracks and predictions.
[image]